# Is there an easy way to wake up my program when a Vulkan fence is signalled?

Tags: linux, vulkan, libev

I'm writing a program that uses libev to wait on many file descriptors. When data comes in, a vulkan compute shader gets run to process the data. The completion of that shader is signalled with a fence. I'd rather not block my event loop to wait for completion to return results.

I originally tried getting a file descriptor using `VkGetFenceFdKHR`, with the `VK_EXTERNAL_FENCE_HANDLE_TYPE_SYNC_FD_BIT` set on the fence to get a sync file, but one of the computers that i'm targetting doesn't support that feature.

For the time being, i'm just polling the fences with a timer and `vkGetFenceStatus`, but that feels really inefficient. is there a better way to wake up my event loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Waiting on "many file descriptors" doesn't "block my event loop", but somehow waiting on a fence would? Can you just have the thread that waits on file descriptors also wait on the fence (separately from the FDs)?

Comment: I can pass the file descriptors to `select` and wait on all of them at once, whereas there's no way to simultaneously wait on the fence. I'm sorry if i wasn't clear...

Comment: Ignoring the possibility of a deadlock, wouldn't it be equivalent to just wait on your FDs, then wait on the fence, since you're not supposed to progress until all of them have cleared?

Comment: It's not really equivelant, because the f'd's represent data coming in from various sources (cameras, the network, etc) and that data has to be reacted to quickly. When i wait on the fence, incoming data from other sources isn't being handled

Comment: I guess I don't understand what `select` is doing. Is your thread waking up when *any* FD is set, or only when *all* of them are set? If it's the former, how do you decide which task to perform? Does `select` return which FD woke it up?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what select does; given a set of events, it waits until one or more of them has happened, and let's you know which one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a *better* way, as I have no real experience with file-descriptor based synchronization. But here's an alternative.

You can create a thread whose sole purpose is to block on the fence, after which it will signal an FD. That's probably better in some respects than your timer&polling API, as it's not wasting CPU cycles. But it does require an extra thread wake-up before the thread that's waiting on the FD can see it, so that may delay responsiveness.

Comment: yeah i've been trying to avoid adding threads, but i'll give it a shot, thanks